# Can I Serialize Vector3 in my Save Options file

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

I am working on saving and loading options for a game and I am trying to Serialize a Vector3 but I received this error :

```
SerializationException: Type UnityEngine.Vector3 is not marked as Serializable.
```

When I look at the documentation I see Vector3 on this list of Serializable types :

```
Serializable types are:
- Some built-in types like Vector2, Vector3, Vector4, Quaternion, Matrix4x4, Color, Rect, LayerMask.
```

My code is :

```
public Options_Settings GameOptions { get; private set; }

public void SaveOptionSettings(){
    // Create the Binary Formatter.
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    // Stream the file with a File Stream. (Note that File.Create() 'Creates' or 'Overwrites' a file.)
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/OptionsInfo.dat");
    // Serialize the file so the contents cannot be manipulated.
    bf.Serialize(file, GameOptions);  // <---- Error is here
    // Close the file to prevent any corruptions
    file.Close();
}
```

My Options_Settings :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class Options_Settings {

public bool MusicToggle { get; set; }
public float MusicVolume { get; set; }

public bool SFXToggle { get; set; }
public float SFXVolume { get; set; }

public Vector3 UIOneScaling { get; set; }
public Vector3 UITwoScaling { get; set; }
public Vector3 UIThreeScaling { get; set; }


public void Default () {

    MusicToggle = true;
    MusicVolume = 0.5f;

    SFXToggle = true;
    SFXVolume = 0.5f;

    UIOneScaling = Vector3.one;
    UITwoScaling = Vector3.one;
    UIThreeScaling = Vector3.one;
}
```

}

I know I can make a workaround and just make 3 floats for each vector and pass them around that way but I want to understand what I am doing wrong since the documentation says I can do Vector3 which would prevent extra coding and doing monotonous acts.

Comment: Use [serialization surrogates](http://web.archive.org/web/20141231105711/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx).  See http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/vector3-not-serializable.7766/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While unity CAN indeed serialize a Vector3 variable,  it cannot serialize an ACCESSOR to a Vector3.

I see this accessor in your code:

```
public Vector3 UIOneScaling { get; set; }
```

but I don't see the ACTUAL vector variable being stored: the accessor is just a function.

I would have expected to see something like:

```
[SerializeField]  // needed to serialize private fields
private Vector3 _UIOneScaling; //a member variable to hold the data
public Vector3 UIOneScaling {
    get return {_UIOneScaling;} 
    set {_UIOneScaling=value;} 
}
```

In this case the member *VARIABLE* _UIOneScaling WOULD be serialized.